# Are x-rays in fusion plasmas mostly from collisions with high atomic number ions?

Tags: plasma-physics

Say you have a hot (100eV-1keV) hydrogen plasma with no impurities in it and no collisional interaction with the wall. Would this plasma radiate x-rays?

X-rays are from bremsstrahlung, so could collisions between electrons and protons produce x-rays or do you need collisions with higher atomic number atoms?

Would the brightest (x-ray) part of the plasma be the centre, where it is hottest and densest?

Comment: You're looking for *collisional excitation*, which I do not believe is in the X-ray band.

Comment: You could, in theory, get X-rays just from thermal emission if your gas is hot enough.  Think of a blackbody with a peak in the far UV or X-ray range.  This is possible, as evidenced in the solar corona where thermal bremsstrahlung occurs.  I do not think you need heavy elements or line emissions, just enough kinetic in one of the particles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a plasma consisting only of electrons and hydrogen ions will emit x-rays due to **free-free radiation**: an electron is accelerated towards an ion when passing it, thus slightly changing its trajectory. While being attracted towards the ion, the electron loses some kinetic energy which is emitted as electromagnetic radiation in the x-ray spectrum.

Ions with more protons have a stronger effect on passing electrons and bremsstrahlung (x-ray) losses due to heavier ions are larger as compared to losses in a pure hydrogen plasma. (This is why impurities can be such a problem in a fusion plasma.)

Also, more power is radiated away (as x-rays/bremsstrahlung) when the plasma density is higher (the power density scales with $n^2$ and with $T_e^{-0.5}$).